# Multithreading modules

Tags: salt-stack

One of my modules takes up to 5 minutes to execute due to underlying shell commands. I would like to change this and either make the executing asynchronous or start commands in separate threads/processes. Unfortunately I could not find any example of such approach.

Is it possible to run some steps of the module inside separate thread? Do you know example of it? I've been searching through modules inside salt repository, none is using multithreading nor multiprocessing, so I got lost.

Answer (score 1):

You usually want to be sure that your minion is in the correct state after you've executed:

`salt '*' state.highstate`

I guess that it is not meant to be asynchonous.

You might want to change your bash script to execute the stuff in seperate threads. I would use a language that i know - python or nodejs. It mostly depends on what this bash script actually does.

Comment: well if I have bunch of long running and non-blocking tasks, I could run them all in the same time and wait for the time of the longest one rather then sum of waiting for each of them?

Comment: exactly - salt calls your threading worker script, which manages the execution and waiting. finally this script exits and salt proceeds with the next state.